# Angular $remove() and express delete()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

How can I processed http DELETE request with express.js, created by angular-service's default $remove() method?
I have working post method:
On client (specifically inside angular controller):

```
$scope.obj.$save();
```

On server:

```
myRouter.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var param = req.body.some_parameter; // got it fine
});
```

But it doesn't work with delete :)
On client:

```
obj.$remove();
```

On server:

```
myRouter.delete('/', function(req, res) {
    //this route will be called, but I want get obj parametr like in post method
    //can I do that? Or I shoud use request with parameter instead (?param=val)

    //here I get undefined
    var param = req.body.some_parameter;
});
```

Comment: Does it mean that you want to send the `obj` object with your DELETE request? If yes, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159213/pretty-coding-to-send-body-with-delete-request-in-angular-js

Comment: @lukaszfiszer, I thought obj will sended :) Seems like I was wrong.